# Ellipsis for right aligned text

Tags: html, css

I want to have an ellipsis for text that's right aligned. The ellipsis happen when the text is left aligned or if the break happens in the middle of a word.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: pink;
}

p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="right">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="right">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quickss brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quickss brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</div>
```

The first box is when it breaks after a word while the 2nd box breaks on a word (`quickss`). The last 2 boxes are when both are left aligned.

The solution I need is purely CSS so no ClampJS.

Thanks.

--

UPDATE:

The picture below will explain the problem a bit more visually. The two boxes below has the same styling except for the text `quick` in the 2nd sentence.

Text for the first box:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

Text for the second box:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quickss brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

Notice how the first box doesn't show the ellipsis because it breaks after `quick` while the 2nd box shows the ellipsis becausse it breaks within the word `quickss`.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The right aligned text is being ellipsized in your example.

Comment: You'll need to see the preview in full page cause there's 4 boxes but the preview only shows 3 boxes because of its default height.

Comment: I don't understand too. Can you be more precise with example for instance like even it is not working now, just saw this need to work and this will always failed

Comment: More detail added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is purely CSS and the aim is to add the ellipsis when you needed (source: http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/ )

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-right: 2em; /*1em from normal padding + 1em from '...' width*/
  background-color: pink;
}

/* styles for '...' */ 
.block-with-text {
  /* hide text if it more than N lines  */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* for set '...' in absolute position */
  position: relative; 
  /* use this value to count block height */
  line-height: 1.2em;
  /* max-height = line-height (1.2) * lines max number (2) */
  max-height: 2.4em; 
  /* fix problem when last visible word doesn't adjoin right side  */
  text-align: right;  
  /* place for '...' */
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
/* create the ... */
.block-with-text:before {
  /* points in the end */
  content: '...';
  /* absolute position */
  position: absolute;
  /* set position to right bottom corner of block */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
/* hide ... if we have text, which is less than or equal to max lines */
.block-with-text:after {
  /* points in the end */
  content: '';
  /* absolute position */
  position: absolute;
  /* set position to right bottom corner of text */
  right: 0;
  /* set width and height */
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  /* bg color = bg color under block */
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>

<p class="block-with-text">Here is a paragraph with a lotof text, but onlytwfdo visi ble lines. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Arcu tellus, ultricies at vestibulum sit amet, malesuada non purus.</p>

</div>
```