# Css Ellipsis issue- Either show full word or ellipsis if there is more text, not half word with ellipsis

Tags: html, css, overflow, ellipsis

I have a scenario, text in the table header, that also can be multiline. What I'm struggling with is,
I need to show ellipsis only after a full word, don't want to break the word. Now I need it in a multiline and right-align text also.
I have tried various CSS solutions available on SO.
I can't have a fixed width.

```
word-break: break-all // not doing the job

::before & ::after // worked but only for last word
```

I tried this: **[Ellipsis for right aligned text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287394/ellipsis-for-right-aligned-text)**

HTML:

```
<div class="column-header-container" style="display: flex;"><span class="column-name align-right" style="flex-grow: 1; -webkit-line-clamp: 1);"><div class="header-title-text">Right Aligned</div></span></div>
```

Requirement:
Show ellipsis if there is more text, show ellipsis only after a full word, donot break the word for ellipsis.

Any CSS expert.

Comment: if you could post your html code? it will be more helpful.

Comment: Can you please post your full code so we can attempt to reproduce the issue? It's not entirely clear what it is you're looking to achieve without seeing a reproducible example. In the meantime, you could look into the `text-overflow` attribute and see if that helps. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: Not able to edit the question, here is the HTML: @Amitkumar @AStombaugh

`
<div> <span style="text-align: right"> <div>Text here<div></span>